# How to kill a specific task in windows 2012 server

Tags: windows, cmd

This is for windows 2012 server. I am trying to kill a specific task running under cmd window. [image]

In this specific case I want to kill SWIMAUX. I have a command prompt open and every time I use taskkill command I get the following error. How can I kill that task?

```
C:\Siemens\hot_cold_backups>taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq SWIMAUX"

INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.


C:\Siemens\hot_cold_backups>taskkill /f /fi "services eq SWIMAUX"

INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either specify the image name for the process you want to kill or the window title.

If the window has a specific title, then you can use the `WINDOWTITLE` parameter of the taskkill command

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq SWIMAUX"
```

### To find the image name of a process:

1. Open task manager and right click on the process you want to kill, and select `Go to details`
2. Find the highlighted executable and use it in your `taskkill` command, eg. `taskkill /f /t /im process.exe`

[image: Right click]

Answer (score -1):

step 1:netstat -ano | findstr :
      You should be known your PORT number

Step 2:taskkill /PID  /F

id will be shown in the end of the TCP connection data in the result of above command